# Как вырезать от и до на php?

Tags: php

Как получить выражением в PHP из `<img src="vk.com/logo/logo.png" alt="logos" title="logos">` только значение src="", т.е. `vk.com/logo/logo.png`

Comment: Есть несколько вариантов: библиотеки для разбора `HTML`, регулярное выражение, поиск подстрок

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть несколько вариантов: библиотеки для разбора `HTML`, регулярное выражение, поиск подстрок...

Воспользуемся регулярным выражением

```php
<?php

$img = '<img src="vk.com/logo/logo.png" alt="logos" title="logos">';

preg_match('/src="([^"]+)"/', $img, $src);

print_r($src);
```

Вывод

```php
Array
(
    [0] => src="vk.com/logo/logo.png"
    [1] => vk.com/logo/logo.png
)
```